# Beer is banned in my state. How can I make beer at my home?

Tags: wine, specialty-beers, alcohol

I am living in Germany, I am addicted to beer, but if I go back to my country, I couldn't find the beer or any alcohol products at my state, because beer and alcohol are banned. Is there any way, I can make beer at home.

Comment: This seems like a question of law, rather than about beer or spirits. This question would be equal to any other policy like, "My country passed a new law, how can I avoid compliance?" Voting to close. I would suggest law.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Trying to circumvent would be difficult. Supplies [probably] couldn't be shipped or mailed safely, since those are probably monitored. It is unlikely you are the only person in your area who are legally disallowed beer that deals similarly with this. Outside of your taking the personal risk to purchase and transport your supplies, you would be endangering others unnecessarily. Again legal, not beer, issue.

Comment: This is a legit question. We aren't going to close it.

Comment: This might be better posted on the Law SE site.

Comment: Please post this at https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/ you'll find much better help than legal advice from other contributors.

Comment: Are you asking about *permission* or about *technique* (how to homebrew)?  If the latter, can you [edit] to clarify what restrictions apply?  For example, are you able to get supplies?  (Does your locale ban *selling* alcohol or *owning/making* it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you read this thread in Reddit on a guy in Kyrgyzstan trying to make beer from basic ingredients and malting his own barley at home. This is what it might take to make beer from scratch. https://www.reddit.com/r/Homebrewing/comments/ag67o4/kyrgyzstan_primitive_brew_full_write_up_and/

Answer (score 0):

If you are gone make your own beer make sure that when you are making to write everything down that you use for at least the grams of possible better and also how long you did each stage because 30 min longer brewing or malting has a significant impact on the final result. And when you are doing it I would like to read about your results.